# Constraining a parametric plot

Tags: plotting, constraint

I have the following parametric plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{u + 2800*v, v}, {u, -1/2, 1/2}, {v, -4, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-1/1000, 1/1000}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "x'"}]
```

I now wish to restrict the x coordinates as $-3/2 \leq x \leq 3/2$. In other words only the part of the region for which $-3/2 \leq u + 2800 v \leq 3/2$ holds, is the desired region, see illustration below. How can I implement this? [image]

Comment: To restrict to a region, add the option `RegionFunction -> Function[{u, v}, -(3/2) <= u + 2800 v <= 3/2]` to your `ParametricPlot` (however, this seems to end up plotting nothing, so I'm not sure whether this set of parameters makes sense?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, your suggestion is indeed what I am looking for I suppose, but trying it this way, I end up with nothing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion) instead:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[
    {{u + 2800 v, v}, -3/2 < u + 2800 v < 3/2},
    {{u,-1/2,1/2}, {v,-4,4}}
];
```

Then, you can create your desired graphics with:

```
Show[
    Region@reg,
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-2/1000, 2/1000}},
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "x'"},
    Frame -> True,
    Axes->True
]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use a region specification for the parameters:

```
region = RegionIntersection[
    Rectangle[{-1/2, -4}, {1/2, 4}],
    ImplicitRegion[-3/2 < u + 2800 v < 3/2, {u, v}]
];
ParametricPlot[
    {u + 2800 v, v},
    {u, v} ∈ region,
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2/1000, 2/1000}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "x'"}
]
```

[image]